# InstallShield: копирование дополнительного файла

Tags: installshield

Дистрибутив подготовлен при помощи InstallShield. Как сделать, чтобы, при установке, из папки с дистрибутивом в папку установки копировался дополнительный файл?

Т.е. до установки имеем:
C:\Soft\Setup.exe
C:\Soft\Config.xml

а после установки:
C:\Program files\Our App\Program.exe
C:\Program files\Our App\Config.xml

Как это сделать?